# concatenate two Lists

Tags: java, arrays, list, generics

I'm trying to make a simple program that takes two lists and concatenates them together. I can't seem to figure out the logic to make this work though. The part that isn't working is the: return statement.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ListConcatenate {
public static void main(String[] args) {


List<String> list = new List<>();
List<String> secondList = new List<>();
list.insertAtFront("Hello");
list.insertAtBack("World");
secondList.insertAtFront("it's");
secondList.insertAtFront("me");
}
public static<E> List<E> concatenate(List<E> list, List<E> secondList){


    //List<E> newList = new List<>();


    return new ArrayList<E>(){{
        addAll(list);
        addAll(secondList);
    }};
    }




}
```

Comment: You Never call concatinate

Comment: It is underlined in red so calling it will simply cause an exception report.

Comment: How can you `new List<>();`? It's interface.

Comment: Underlying red means that your IDE is telling you about a compiler error. You used incorrect syntax then. And the term exception *report* doesn't carry any meaning in Java.

Comment: And hint: your style of doing new() with that following code creates an anonymous inner class. Albeit this is possible, it is a strongly discouraged bad practice.

Comment: I realize I didn't give enough info. I have a generic class called List. I'm basically attempting to make my own linked list without using the built in list.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use List::addAll

`list.addAll (secondList); return list;`

See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-arraylist-addall-method-java/

Answer (score 0):

`List` is an interface. you cant instantiate the `List`. use `ArrayList`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Hello");
    list.add(0, "World");
    secondList.add("it's");
    secondList.add("me");
    concatenate(list, secondList).forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  public static <E> List<E> concatenate(List<E> list, List<E> secondList) {
    List<E> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    newList.addAll(list);
    newList.addAll(secondList);
    return newList;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that I would want to point out.
Use run time polymorphism correctly. You can't instantiate an interface.

If you want to insert something at front use the add method that takes in index and the element. If you want to insert something at the back, simply use the add method. I tried editing your code and it seems to work perfectly fine. Good Luck!
Here you go :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class ListConcatenate {
public static void main(String[] args) {


List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(0,"Hello");
list.add("World");
secondList.add(0,"it's");
secondList.add(0,"me");
List<String> result = concatenate(list,secondList);
for(String s : result ) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
}
public static<E> List<E> concatenate(List<E> list, List<E> secondList){


    //List<E> newList = new List<>();


    return new ArrayList<E>(){{
        addAll(list);
        addAll(secondList);
    }};
    }




}
```